# SPWeb http://sp/hr is not rendering but all others are

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site

Today one of our sharePoint web sites (SPWEB) `http://sp/hr` stopped responding. But all of the other sites are running just fine. Is there any way to reset the site? I tried to reboot the server but no luck. Powershell commands are welcomed.

Comment: Have you seen that all application pools are started in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

as viraj stated check iis:

goto iis manager, check application pools are all running.

next goto "web sites" and look for the site that hosts the web.

click on the folder "web sites" on the right you should see the list and check the state is running. If not right click on that site and click start.

If all fails restart iis:

**To restart IIS using IIS Manager**

> 1.
>
> In IIS Manager, right click the local computer, point to All Tasks,
>   then click Restart IIS.
>
> 2.
>
> In the What do you want IIS to do list, click Restart Internet
>   Services on computername.
>
> 3.
>
> IIS attempts to stop all services before restarting. IIS waits up to
>   five minutes for all services to stop. If the services cannot be
>   stopped within five minutes, all IIS services are terminated, and IIS
>   restarts. In addition, clicking End now forces all IIS services to
>   stop immediately, and IIS is restarted.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx?mfr=true